# How would I prove $-3x^2-1<0$ for all values of $x$ by induction?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

I am having difficulty in figuring out how to proceed with the $k+1$ case for the following

> Prove $-3x^2-1<0$  for all values of $x\in\mathbb N$

Here's what I have got so far

Let $P_k$ be the statement that for some value $x=k$, $k\in \mathbb N$ :
$$-3k^2-1<0$$

$P_1$ for the case where $k=1$:

$$-3(1)^2-1=-4<0  $$
Hence $P_k$ true for $k=1$ 
 
$P_{k+1}$:

$$-3(k+1)^2-1<0$$

Comment: Did you forget $-$ in the title?

Comment: Thank you, fixed it.

Comment: Which set does $x$ belong to?

Comment: You mean $x\in \mathbb N$, right?

Comment: Yes, an error on my part again I apologize

Comment: Hint: let $S_k$ be $-3k^2-1$, so your $P_k$ is the statement that $S_k\lt 0$. Can you come up with an inequality between $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$? Once you do, you should be able to use transitivity of the $\lt$ relation to finish the induction.

Comment: Getting close. What's another formula equal to $(-3(k+1)^2-1)$?

Comment: IMO doing this by induction is a rather ineffective way to do it.  $x^2 \ge 0$.  So $3x^2 \ge 0$ and $-3x^2 \le 0$ and $-3x^2 - 1 \le -1 < 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *know*  $-3x^2 -1 < 0$ and you want to *prove* $-3(x+1)^2 - 1< 0$ *from* $-3x^2 - 1< 0$.

Okay.... Let's kick the ball around a bit .... what *is* $-3(x+1)^2 -1$?

$-3(x+1)^2 - 1 = -3(x^2 + 2x +1)-1 = -3x^2 -6x-4$.  How does that compare to $-3x^2 - 1$?

Well $-3x^2 -6x-2 = -3x^2 - 1 -(6x+3)$.  Now $-3x^2 -1 < 0$ so sso $-3x^2 - (6x+3) < 0 -(6x+3)$.

$x > 0$ and $6x > 0$ and $6x + 3 > 3$ and $-(6x+3) < -3$ and $(-3x^2 -1) - (6x+3) < -(6x+3) < -3 < 0$.

So that's that.

$-3(x+1)^2 - 1 = -3(x^2 + 2x + 1) - 1=$

$-3x^2 - 6x -4 = (-3x^2 -1)-6x -3 < $

$0 - 6x -3 < -3 < 0$.